# VBA code with if function (values taken from the cell)

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code which uses countif function and checks if the value "United States" is populated in the Test column *(see the code below)*.

I would like to make this more flexible and I want it to get the data from the specific column (e.g. A2) instead of static value "United States".

I know that this piece of code should be amended

```
Debug.Print "=IF(RC[" & CStr(FormulaCol - LookupCol - 1) & "]=""United States"",1,0)"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, FormulaCol - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[" & CStr(LookupCol -     FormulaCol) & "]=""United States"",1,0)"
```

I tried to use the simple function code =IF(B2=A2,1,0) and put A2 in the code. All my tries returned the syntax error.

**My Macro**

```
Sub bbb()
Dim FormulaCol As Long
Dim LookupCol As Long
Dim TotalRows As Long
Dim TotalCols As Long
Dim i As Long

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
TotalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
TotalCols = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

For i = 1 To TotalCols
If Cells(1, i).Value = "Test" Then
    LookupCol = i
    Exit For
End If
Next

For i = 1 To TotalCols
If Cells(1, i).Value = "Values" Then
    FormulaCol = i
    Range("A2").Activate
    Debug.Print "=IF(RC[" & CStr(FormulaCol - LookupCol - 1) & "]=""United States"",1,0)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, FormulaCol - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[" & CStr(LookupCol - FormulaCol) & "]=""United States"",1,0)"
    Cells(2, FormulaCol).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, FormulaCol), Cells(TotalRows, FormulaCol))
    With Range(Cells(2, FormulaCol), Cells(TotalRows, FormulaCol))
    .Value = .Value
    End With
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `R2C1` instead of `A2` in the function.  The reason for this is that you are using `Range.FormulaR1C1`, which accepts only RC-style references.

The VBA line which assigns the formula to the cell will then look like this:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, FormulaCol - 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[" & CStr(LookupCol - FormulaCol) & "]=R2C1,1,0)"
```

Comment: hi Ikh. That works. Thank you. I was thinking is there any easy way to specify the column header (i mean: find the "Geo" column and use the value below the header)?

Comment: @mgunia do you mean that you wish to use an arbitrary column name instead of `"Test"`?

Answer (score 0):

... Replace `"]=""United States"",1,0)"` with `"]=" & Range("A2").Value & ",1,0)"`

That should do the trick...